# Expand current Javascript text box content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

At the moment I have a javascript/jquery snippet that changes text in a text box depending on which icon/image is currently hovered over. It currently uses the ID tag name as the display string. How can I get it to display some other text (based on same image hover) - i.e. instead of using the ID string like "idOne" I can use another string like "This is the text to be displayed" for that particular ID element (.attr('id'))
As you can gather I'm pretty new to this! Will appreciate any guidance.
Thanks

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var text=$('#explain-text').text();
      $('#idOne,#idTwo,#OidThree,#idFour,#idFive').hover(function() {
         $('#explain-text').text($(this).attr('id'));
       },function(){
         $('#explain-text').text(text);
   });
  });
```

Comment: Can you post your html plz ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add other attribute in your `img` tag like this:
`<img id="one" src="images.png" alt="Smiley face" info="This is the text to be displayed" >`

And then, in your JS file, get its value as below:

```
$('#explain-text').val($(this).attr("info"));
```

Comment: Thanks NekoMi. This code is running is in a wordpress site and I can't find anywhere to add the info attribute - I don't suppose you would know how I add that attribute to an image do you? Thnx